# Manipulate Meta Description Content using Joomla Module

Tags: module, header, metadata

I want to create a Joomla Module that has the capability to write its own text based on the GET data within the submitted URL, it sounds feasible, let's say the submitted URL is

```
yourdomain.com/index.php?yourarea=JAKARTA
```

then the created text is

```
JAKARTA is within our service coverage area
```

Now I want the `JAKARTA is within our service coverage area` to be visible in the Description metadata in the HTML Header, it is the Joomla website of course. it should look like this

```
<head>
<meta name="description" content="JAKARTA is within our service coverage area">
</head>
```

Consider Google SEO, I want this meta description to be rendered as early as possible because I want Google to Catch this and recognize it as valid metadata.
Can we do that?

Comment: Very old related content on Joomla Forum: [How to put Meta Description in Component ?](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=483319) and here are some old ones (that could benefit from some modern advice) from Stack Overflow: [Joomla add some meta tags one page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57468123/2943403) and [How to dynamically set og:image meta tag with php in joomla?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20645843/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with something like:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$keyword = Factory::getApplication()->input->get('yourarea', '', 'string');
$document = Factory::getDocument();

if($keyword)
{
    $document->setDescription($keyword . ' is within our service coverage area');
}
```